# WPF Calendar: Customize the control to show calendar week numbers

Tags: wpf, calendar, custom-controls

Currently i'm creating a Custom Calendar Control that inherits from the Standard WPF Calendar.

Thanks to Mr. Veeneman i got Highlighting for specific dates to work http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ExtendingWPFCalendar.aspx.

Now i'm trying to add the weeknumbers to the left of the standard "days-block" but do not know how to accomplish this task.

Has anyone created a Custom Calendar with such a functionality willing to share his thoughts?

I try to avoid to use WPF Toolkit from Codeplex since i have had rather mediocre experiences with the toolkits for asp.net.

with kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You mention the WPF Toolkit yourself, and which is what Charles Petzold has used to add week numbers: http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/10/Adapting-the-Calendar-Control-for-Week-Numbers.html

I am also looking for a way to add week numbers to the default WPF Calendar control. Is the principles of WPF Calendar different from WPF Toolkit Calendar?

Comment: I do not work on this anymore but as far as i remember the WPF Calendar's functionality is very rudimentary and provides only very few customization options. I believe it is easier to implement a complete Calendar control from scratch.